# googlemapに2か所以上のマークを付ける。

Tags: monaca, google-maps

すみません。アプリの中に地図を埋め込みたいのですが2か所以上マークを付ける方法が分かりません。
iframeを使って手っ取り早く2か所以上のマークを付ける方法はありますでしょうか？

```html
<div style="width: 360px; height:600px; overflow: hidden;">
        <iframe src= "http://maps.google.co.jp/maps?q=東京都新宿区西新宿2-8-1 &z=15&output=embed" width="360px" height="600px" frameborder="0" style="border:0; margin-top: -40%;"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

google map api を使ってはいかがでしょうか？

■ Google Map API ドキュメント
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=ja
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=ja

■ 日本語の参考サイト
http://www.nanchatte.com/map/showDifferentInfoWindowOnEachMarker.html
http://tanaka8.com/2011/11/google-map-markers/
※他にも検索すると沢山出てきます。